How to get a column as Option<String> out of a polars DataFrame?
I am trying to get a Vec<Option<String>> so I can pass it to sqlx with null values intact. Based on this SO question, I've tried:
let names: Vec<Option<String>> = merged_df
    .column("description")?
    .str()?
    .into_iter()
    .map(|s| s.to_string())
    .collect();

But this is failing with:
 1  error[E0599]: the method `to_string` exists for enum `Option<&str>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
     --> rust/load_all.rs:569:20
      |
 569  |         .map(|s| s.to_string())
      |                    ^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Option<&str>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
      |
     ::: /Users/nick/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/option.rs:570:1
      |
 570  | pub enum Option<T> {
      | ------------------ doesn't satisfy `_: TemporalMethods`, `std::option::Option<&str>: AsSeries`, `std::option::Option<&str>: ToString
 ` or `std::option::Option<&str>: std::fmt::Display`
      |
      = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
              `std::option::Option<&str>: AsSeries`
              which is required by `std::option::Option<&str>: polars::prelude::TemporalMethods`
              `std::option::Option<&str>: std::fmt::Display`
              which is required by `std::option::Option<&str>: ToString`

How can I get this to work?

You're missing one map(). You need two: one for the iterator, the other for the Option:
let names: Vec<Option<String>> = merged_df
    .column("description")?
    .str()?
    .into_iter()
    .map(|s| s.map(|s| s.to_string()))
    .collect();

Side note, you should prefer working with native Polars operations than converting like that. It'll be more efficient.

Thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate on your last point? I’m only doing this conversion because the compiler is asking me to; if I can avoid it, even better!

@NickK9 I don't know what you are trying to do so I can't tell if it can be done without conversion; all I mean is that if you can do what you want without conversion, using Polars APIs, it's better.

@NickK9 in other words, what are you doing with names? Can you do that with the polars iterators rather than using polars iterators to copy to vec and then doing the real thing?

Chayim's answer will work if you really need to get a Vec<Option<String>> out of a Polars Series. However, this sqlx issue helped me understand that this conversion is not actually necessary when passing NULL-able strings to sqlx. You can just use a cast instead. In the end, here's the code I went with:
let names: Vec<Option<&str>> = merged_df
    .column("description")?
    .str()?
    .iter()
    .collect();

let _ = query!(
    "INSERT INTO district_resources (name)
        SELECT * FROM UNNEST (
            $1::text[]
        )",
    &names as &[Option<&str>]
)

